# Getting an error consuming asmx web service as add service reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, visual-studio-2012

I have created sample web application which consumes old asmx web service(which is already hosted on network server) using add service reference. It has created endpoint, basicHttpBinding, etc. when I'm running this application in visual studio 2012 without an extra settings, its working. After I published it and hosted it on IIS, it gives an error as given below :

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

```
[SocketException (0x2746): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) +6508791
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +130

[IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.]
   System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +296
   System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size) +19
   System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead) +251

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6442392
   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout) +55

[CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to (http://"web service path"). This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10618399
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +336
   TestEvantekWebApp.wsCMA.CMAMobileSoap.GetQueueInfo(GetQueueInfoRequest request) +0
   TestEvantekWebApp.wsCMA.CMAMobileSoapClient.TestEvantekWebApp.wsCMA.CMAMobileSoap.GetQueueInfo(GetQueueInfoRequest request) in c:\Users\vishwajeet.kulkarni\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestEvantekWebApp\TestEvantekWebApp\Service References\wsCMA\Reference.cs:721
   TestEvantekWebApp.wsCMA.CMAMobileSoapClient.GetQueueInfo(String tenantID, Int32 pax) in c:\Users\vishwajeet.kulkarni\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestEvantekWebApp\TestEvantekWebApp\Service References\wsCMA\Reference.cs:729
   TestEvantekWebApp.TestEvantekPage.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\vishwajeet.kulkarni\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\TestEvantekWebApp\TestEvantekWebApp\TestEvantekPage.aspx.cs:21
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

My Web.config file of web application:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="102400" />    
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>    
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="Web"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="CMAMobileSoap" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                     openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />          
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://1.1.1.1/capitaws/CMAMobile.asmx"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CMAMobileSoap"
          contract="wsCMA.CMAMobileSoap" name="CMAMobileSoap">
        <identity>
          <dns value="1.1.1.1"/>
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This bit of the exception seems pretty helpful... `An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to (http://"web service path"). This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.` Have you checked the server error logs? Of course, I'm assuming that you've actually set the web service path properly in your config and that the IIS server can do a DNS lookup of the hostname you're using?

Comment: Please post on how your config looks like?

Comment: @Basic: What exactly you meant to say? I didn't get. I tried some more things but I'm still getting the same error. Any specific hint can push me ahead.

Comment: @Rajesh: I'm adding my config in question. Please have a look.

Comment: The error tells you it can't open a connection, check the server log files (that is the log files of the old web service). Have you done this?

Comment: @Basic:I checked it. The exception message is : 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/$metadata'.

Comment: How about your server side config?

Comment: @Rajesh: What exactly? You want code sample or else? It is just plain traditional asmx web service config file. The thing is service data can be when I'm calling it from VS IDE but from IIS hosted app is showing an error. When I debugged, I noticed service object is not getting no. of methods are exposed by the service & it is giving an error : function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out.

Comment: The more information you provide the easier it is to help. Since its an asmx service are you able to access the wsdl when hosted on IIS?

Comment: @Rajesh : Yes, I can access its wsdl too from my machine. Actually, the service is installed on another remote server.

Comment: I guess the best way to access a asmx service would be to do a add reference and then see if you can access it or create a proxy class from the wsdl and then use it to access the asmx service. The above configuration shows you are trying to access the service using basicHttpBinding(WCF) that is causing the exception